# How to close or Hide the Dialog box in C# when the timer interval is going?

Tags: c#

I have developed a windows application by using c# to display the battery status of laptop when it is not in charging. I have used timers in Winforms to update the battery status for every 1 minute. My requirement is when the user starts to charge his laptop battery, at that time the dialog box which shows battery status should be suddenly closed or hidden.

The problem here i am facing is the timer runs for every minute and then it closes the dialog box after 1 minute from switching to charge the laptop battery. But i need to be close the dialog box immediately when the user starts charging his laptop battery.

Comment: Please provide some code of your app. Is it win service? Or just Winforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged` event. Inside the handler, you should additionally check that status changed because of connected charger.

```
    SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged;

    public void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Mode==PowerModes.StatusChange && SystemInformation.PowerStatus.BatteryChargeStatus==BatteryChargeStatus.Charging)
            //your action
    }
```

Comment: Thanks cyberj0g. It worked as we expected. Thank you very much